# can this JavaScript function be refactored?

Tags: javascript, optimization, prototypejs

I need to use prototype JavaScript library on a project and wanted to add tabbed box to HTML.

The click handler has a simple task - set selected on parent `<li>` element and show linked DIV id  element (rel tag on `<li>` has element id name)

```
<div class="tabInterface">
  <ul class="tabSelector">
     <li class="selected" rel="searchLast"><a href="#">Popularna iskanja</a></li>
     <li rel="searchMine"><a href="#">Moje zadnje iskanje</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="tabContent selected" id="searchMine">
      box 1 content
  </div>
  <div class="tabContent" id="searchLast">
     box 2 content

  </div> 
</div>
```

Final result after 1 hour of hard labour.

```
initTabInterface = function() {
    //requires prototype
    var tabClick = function(event){
        Event.stop(event);
        var $el = Event.element(event);

        var $menu = $el.up('.tabSelector');
        var liList = $menu.descendants().filter(function(el){return el.match('li')});
        liList.invoke('removeClassName', 'selected');
        $el.up().addClassName('selected');

        var rel = $el.up().readAttribute('rel');
        var $interface = $menu.up('.tabInterface');
        var tabList = $interface.descendants().filter(function(el){return el.match('.tabContent')});
        tabList.invoke('removeClassName', 'selected');
        $interface.down('#'+rel).addClassName('selected');
    };

    $$('.tabInterface .tabSelector li a').each(function(el){
        var $el = $(el);
        Event.observe($el, 'click', tabClick);
    });
};
Event.observe(window,"load", function(){
    initTabInterface();
});
```

Is there an easier way of traversing in prototype than with the bunch of up, down, filter, match, invoke and each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is pretty much you can get:

```
initTabInterface = function() {
    //requires prototype
    var tabClick = function(event){
        Event.stop(event);         
        var $el = Event.element(event);
        var rel = $el.up().readAttribute('rel');

        // remove old selected classes
        $el.up('.tabInterface').select('.selected')
                               .invoke('removeClassName', 'selected');

        // add new selected classes
        [ $(rel), $el.up() ].invoke('addClassName', 'selected');
    };

    $$('.tabSelector li a').each(function(el){
        Event.observe($(el), 'click', tabClick);
    });
};
Event.observe(window,"load", function(){
    initTabInterface();
});​
```

Comment: That is it, select method was what I was looking for, but instead got sidetracked with descendants, filter, findAll, grep and others. Prototype is just so method poluted ...

Answer (score 0):

I do not know Prototype well enough to quickly refactor your code, but you can use `Element.siblings` instead of going up and then descending down. Alternatively, you can just enumerate by class names (doesn't work well if you have more than one tab control).

```
$el.siblings().invoke('removeClassName', 'selected');
```

Also

```
$interface.down('#'+rel).addClassName('selected');
```

is unnecessary because you can only have one element with an id in the whole document. Can change it to:

```
$(rel).addClassName('selected');
```